# Custom hashMap to serve multiple searches for different key

Tags: java, android, hashmap

Recently this question was asked in the interview and interviewer was more concerned to any third-party library which serve this purpose.

If i've an Employee class with

```
String firstName;
int id;
String lastName;
```

If i want to search an employee using id , i need to use id as key and employee as value in my HashMap

```
HashMap<Integer,Employee>
```

What if i want to use my key as firstName now then i need to make another hashMap as `HashMap<String,Employee>`

Is there any standard library where i don't need to make multiple Maps for searching purpose using different keys.
What if i want to use id+firstName as search criteria and value as Employee object?
What if there are 10 attributes and i need to design a data structure to serve this purpose?

Answer (score 0):

You can use SQLite (tagged Android) database so that you can search for records using any attributes.

Comment: Thanks but i would like to do it using Data structure only. I'm curious if there is any library(Google/Guavus) which provide us custom HashMap like this or if we can create our own.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use one `HashMap<String,Employee>`.

As the key use a String that contains the attribute name as the prefix, e.g. `id`, `firstName,`lastName`followed by a separator like`:` and afterwards the value.

This would also allow to use combination of attributes as a key.

If you now add an employee instance to the HashMap add three entries all with the same value.

Example:

```
employee1 = Employee {
  id: 1,
  firstName: "John",
  lastName: "Doe"
}

HashMap: {
   "id:1" -> employee1
   "firstName:John" -> employee1
   "lastName:Doe" -> employee1
}
```

Comment: when it comes to retrieval, I'm passing map.get(1) or map.get("John") or map.get("Doe"). How to differentiate between firstName and lastName even if we concat fN with John and lN with Doe to get the Employee object . What if full names are John Doe and John Loe ? map.get("firstName:John") will give incorrect result. What if full names are John Doe and Doe John . Again wrong results. Isn't ?

Comment: No you pass `map.get("firstName:John")` or `map.get("lastName:Doe")`.

Comment: In case you have multiple entries that map to the same key you need a MultiMap like the one from [Guava](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/NewCollectionTypesExplained#multimap).

Comment: Multimap is i think interviewer was looking to hear from me. Thanks Rober. I'll learn more about it.